# ¿Cómo activar y desactivar checkboxes con otro checkbox a una columna entera de una tabla con jQuery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, django-admin

Como se ve en la CAPTURA quiero *activar* y *desactivar* toda una columna que tiene checkboxs al presionar el checkbox de la parte superior que dice UBIGEO.

[image: Ejemplo de muestra de ACTIVACION DE CHECK]

Con jQuery, este ejemplo viene por defecto en el admin de django.

¿Cómo lo podría hacer?

---

Lo he avanzado así:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>EJEMPLO DE CHECKBOX</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <label for=""><b>CHECK A TODOS</b></label>
        Valor<input type="checkbox" id="checkb" name="check"><br>
         Valor<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="checkbox" class="checar"> <br>
         Valor<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="checkbox" class="checar"><br>
        Valor<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="checkbox" class="checar"><br>
         Valor<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="checkbox" class="checar"><br>


    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            $('#checkb').click(function() {
                $('.checar').each(function(){
                    /*$("#checkbox").click();*/
                    $(this).click();
                })

              });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar el método `prop` tanto para obtener el valor de una propiedad como para establecer el valor a una propiedad para el conjunto de elementos seleccionados.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>EJEMPLO DE CHECKBOX</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="">
        <label for=""><b>CHECK A TODOS</b></label> Valor
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkb" name="check"><br> Valor
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="checkbox" class="checar"> <br> Valor
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="checkbox" class="checar"><br> Valor
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="checkbox" class="checar"><br> Valor
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="checkbox" class="checar"><br>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        // Si se hace click sobre el input de tipo checkbox con id checkb
        $('#checkb').click(function() {
            // Si esta seleccionado (si la propiedad checked es igual a true)
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                // Selecciona cada input que tenga la clase .checar
                $('.checar').prop('checked', true);
            } else {
                // Deselecciona cada input que tenga la clase .checar
                $('.checar').prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Documentación de prop (inglés)](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2)

---

¿Por qué con este código no funciona?

```
$('#checkb').click(function() {
    // No es necesario recorrer cada input con el método each, lo recomendable es utilizar 
    // el selector de clase y modificar el atributo checked directamente a todos los input
    // mediante algún método diseñado para ello (como prop)
    $('.checar').each(function(){
        // Si un input esta seleccionado, al hacer click lo deselecciona y viceversa.
        $(this).click();
    })
});
```

Comment: Esta muy bien @Matias Olivera, pero aun tengo un pequeño detalle:
Por ejemplo todos están con checked ACTIVOS activados con $('#checkb') y de pronto DESCHEQUEO uno de los que tiene esta clase $('.checar'), el Checkbox maestro($('#checkb')) debería de desactivarse, el otro caso es por ejemplo manualmente activos todos los CHECKBOX $('.checar') también el $('#checkb') debería de activarse, como logro hacer ello?, con esto se lograría el mismo funcionamiento que viene en la parte de ADMIN del DJANGO, gracias

Comment: Quizá esta imagen podría complementar lo que quiero https://prnt.sc/fy434e

Answer (score 1):

Amplío la respuesta de Matias Olivera. Pero, como aún no tengo suficiente reputación, no puedo responder en su hilo. Hasta ahora, su propuesta es:

```
// Si se hace click sobre el input de tipo checkbox con id checkb
$('#checkb').click(function() {
   // Si esta seleccionado (si la propiedad checked es igual a true)
   if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      // Selecciona cada input que tenga la clase .checar
      $('.checar').prop('checked', true);
   } else {
      // Deselecciona cada input que tenga la clase .checar
      $('.checar').prop('checked', false);
   }
});
```

Y lo amplío solucionando el pequeño detalle que apunta Alejandro Hurtado. Para solucionar ese detalle he usado este otro método:

```
// Si se hace click sobre el input de tipo checkbox con la clase .checar
$(document).on('change','.checar',function() {
     // Si esta seleccionado (si la propiedad checked es igual a true)
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        // Si todos los checkbox están seleccionados, selecciona el input que tenga id checkb
        if ($('.checar:checked').length == document.getElementById('checar_size').value) {
            $('#checkb').prop('checked', true);
        }
    } else {
        // Deselecciona el input que tenga id checkb
        $('#checkb').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Para que funcione he puesto un campo oculto con id="checar_size" y value = número de checkboxes que hay. Pero si los sabes y no varían como en mi caso, puedes sustituir document.getElementById('checar_size').value por el número de checkboxes.

Espero que sirva de ayuda.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Esos dan un pequño bug xd
vi en esta pagina este ejemplo. 
https://dev.to/juananruiz/marcar-y-desmarcar-checkbox-de-manera-simultanea-con-jquery-523o

Para mi cumple porque desmarcas al menos uno ya no debn estar marcado el "principar".
Esta super XD

```js
$("#selectall").on("click", function() {  
  $(".case").prop("checked", this.checked);  
  });  

  // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox and viceversa  
  $(".case").on("click", function() {  
    if ($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {  
      $("#selectall").prop("checked", true);  
    } else {  
      $("#selectall").prop("checked", false);  
    }  
});
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"></th>
    <th>Participantes</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case[]" value="1"></td>
    <td>Fulano de Tal y Cual</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case[]" value="2"></td>
    <td>Irene Sal de la Cueva</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case[]" value="3"></td>
    <td>Zutano Ruiz Ruiz</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```